# Is it possible to show 10-second loading screen after button is pressed in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I need to show loading screen when press button (until app get data from API) for cca. 10 seconds.

Is it possible and how to do that?

Comment: If you aren't against using modals, you could show a modal while the request completes? You could then hide the modal once you are happy that the data has been fetched successfully.

Comment: are you using redux? then i could suggest a way that could save a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

To answer this properly, you really should first understand the intended code pattern react was intended for (not required but was built to fulfill)

The concept is the Flux design pattern.

Essentially, in flux, you have actions that causes store changes which the view (react) will respond or ‘react’ to.

I suggest for simplicity using the mobx and mobx-react libraries to help facilitate this pattern.

Next you simply create an ‘action’ (a simple method who’s only purpose is to modify the store) for your button like ‘loadData’. This action can initially set loading = true in your store which your react can react to and render a modal to cover the screen and show a loading graphic.

Then the action can asynchronously load in data, then when complete set the loading = false to cause your react to clear the loading screen.

If all of this is way over your head: research flux, then research mobx. It will get clearer very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Loader component which display loading indicator depend on state variable.

For example create a state variable called `isLoading` :

```js
this.state = {
  isLoading: false
}
```

Now when you call the api to fetch data set this state variable to true :

```js
fetchData = () => {
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  axios.get('api_url', { headers: header }).then((res) => {
    this.setState({ data: res.data, isLoading: false });
  }).catch((e) => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false }, () => {
      // show error here 
    });
  })
}
```

In your view put Loader component on the top :

```
import Loader from '../components/Loader';
...
...
render () {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Loader isLoading={this.state.isLoading} />
      ...
      ...
      // Your others component
    </View>
  )
}
```

If you want to create Loader component [here](https://github.com/kishanbharda/ReactReduxSkeleton/blob/master/src/components/Loader.js) is the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can wait for 10 second using timeout function

```
 fetchData() {
    setTimeout(() => {
       // API or Your Functions to get data
    }, 10000);
 }
```